# Что лучше: Clang или OmniCppComplete?

Tags: vim

Здравствуйте! Что лучше `Clang AutoComplete` или `OmniCppComplete` по вашему мнению. На данный момент использую `сlang`, но заметил, что строчные константы он не автодополняет, а также не указывает что принимает функция как аргумент.

Comment: Автодополнение cpp кода в VIM гадкий сложный в настройке непрофессиональный  костыль. Пачка плагинов для Visual Studio решает эту проблему лучше в разы, но даже с ней очень много всего приходится делать руками. Исчерпывающего AAA+ решения для этой проблемы(нормального текстового редактора заточенного специально под синтаксис срр) еще никто так и не предложил насколько мне известно. Если оно появится предложившая компания наверняка заработает очень много долларов, так как избавит толпу C++ программистов по всему миру от нудного ручного труда.

Answer (score 1):

clang autocomplete работает намного лучше чем omnicppcomplete, но очень тормозной.

Помоему единственный более менее нормально работающий плагин для автодополнения это YouCompleteMe https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe , 
хотя и далеко неидеален.